# Python : Where should I place the while loop for this Binary search code to work?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, binary-search

So, I'm just at the beginner level and trying to run this Binary search code. But my code only divides the list "only once" and gives the answer. How do I make it loop till it finds the mid point and give the index value as output.

```
user_input = (int(input("Enter a number you want to find : ")))

lister = [i for i in range(1,100)]






def bi_search(a,user):
  low = 0
  high = len(a)
  mid = int(low + (high-low)/2)
  while True:
    if user < a[mid]:
      low = 0
      high = mid-1
      mid = int(low + (high-low)/2)
      print("Your number is in left half")
      print("Your number is",mid,"thelement in the list")
      break      
    elif user > a[mid]:
      low= mid+1
      high = len(a)
      mid = int(low + (high-low)/2)
      print("Your number is in right half")
      print("Your number is",mid,"th element in the list")
      break      

bi_search(lister,user_input)
```

Comment: the logic in while loop is incorrect, you only need to keep `high = mid-1` and `low= mid+1` this 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few mistakes. You are obtaining `mid` several times and few other mistakes too .I have edited your bi_search and is provided below.

Code :

```
def bi_search(a,user):
        low = 0
        high = len(a)
        while low <= high:   
            mid = low + (high - low) // 2
            val = a[mid]
            if user == val:
                return mid
            elif user > val:
                low = mid+1
            elif user < val:
                high = mid-1
```

Comment: Thank you Billa. This really helped.